# React as webpack external dependency

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have tried many different things to get this working but with no success can I get reactjs out of my webpack build and used as an external:

Here is my webpack file:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "windows.jQuery": "jquery"
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("[name]-[hash].css", {allChunks: true}),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compressor: {
                warnings: false
            }
        }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
    webpack_isomorphic_tools_plugin
  ],
  externals: {
    'jquery': 'jQuery',
    'jquery': '$',
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    'keen-js': 'Keen',
    'immutable': 'Immutable',
    'superagent': 'superagent'
  },
```

and my build analysis:

```
react: 597.97 kB (49.8%)
  fbjs: 32.85 kB (5.49%)
    <self>: 32.85 kB (100%)
  <self>: 565.12 kB (94.5%)
babel-core: 132.01 kB (11.0%)
  core-js: 111.1 kB (84.2%)
    <self>: 111.1 kB (100%)
  <self>: 247 B (0.183%)
fluxible: 52.13 kB (4.34%)
  dispatchr: 24.77 kB (47.5%)
    eventemitter3: 7 kB (28.3%)
      <self>: 7 kB (100%)
    inherits: 672 B (2.65%)
      <self>: 672 B (100%)
    <self>: 17.11 kB (69.1%)
  setimmediate: 6.24 kB (12.0%)
    <self>: 6.24 kB (100%)
  is-promise: 165 B (0.309%)
    <self>: 165 B (100%)
  <self>: 20.97 kB (40.2%)
fluxible-router: 50.76 kB (4.23%)
  routr: 18.22 kB (35.9%)
    path-to-regexp: 9.25 kB (50.7%)
      isarray: 120 B (1.27%)
        <self>: 120 B (100%)
      <self>: 9.13 kB (98.7%)
    <self>: 8.97 kB (49.3%)
  query-string: 1.52 kB (2.99%)
    strict-uri-encode: 168 B (10.8%)
      <self>: 168 B (100%)
    <self>: 1.35 kB (89.2%)
  hoist-non-react-statics: 854 B (1.64%)
    <self>: 854 B (100%)
  inherits: 672 B (1.29%)
    <self>: 672 B (100%)
  <self>: 29.53 kB (58.2%)
bootstrap-sass: 33.37 kB (2.78%)
  <self>: 33.37 kB (100%)
promise: 20.78 kB (1.73%)
  asap: 11.43 kB (55.0%)
    <self>: 11.43 kB (100%)
  <self>: 9.35 kB (45.0%)
react-paginate: 17.27 kB (1.44%)
  classnames: 988 B (5.59%)
    <self>: 988 B (100%)
  react-addons-create-fragment: 59 B (0.334%)
    <self>: 59 B (100%)
  <self>: 16.25 kB (94.1%)
fluxible-addons-react: 16.84 kB (1.40%)
  hoist-non-react-statics: 854 B (4.95%)
    <self>: 854 B (100%)
  <self>: 16 kB (95.0%)
debug: 9.95 kB (0.829%)
  ms: 2.28 kB (22.9%)
    <self>: 2.28 kB (100%)
  <self>: 7.67 kB (77.1%)
react-cookie: 5.05 kB (0.420%)
  cookie: 3.29 kB (65.3%)
    <self>: 3.29 kB (100%)
  <self>: 1.75 kB (34.7%)
webpack: 4.06 kB (0.338%)
  <self>: 0 B (0.00%)
superagent-promise: 2.65 kB (0.221%)
  <self>: 2.65 kB (100%)
copy-to-clipboard: 1.92 kB (0.160%)
  toggle-selection: 807 B (41.0%)
    <self>: 807 B (100%)
  <self>: 1.13 kB (59.0%)
react-google-analytics: 1.58 kB (0.132%)
  <self>: 1.58 kB (100%)
classnames: 1.08 kB (0.0900%)
  <self>: 1.08 kB (100%)
react-dom: 63 B (0.00512%)
  <self>: 63 B (100%)
babel: 49 B (0.00398%)
  <self>: 49 B (100%)
<self>: 253.4 kB (21.1%)
```

As you can see, react is a whopping 49.8% of my build! And a build of 400kb, that's a lot. Any ideas for how to get this working with externals?

Comment: This is not exactly what your asking for, but since your asking for ideas: Take a look at https://github.com/insin/nwb. It has good support for creating React components and libraries. It uses webpack under the hood.

Comment: You want to reduce webpack build time or reduce overall package size? 400kb is nothing comparing to internet speed we all have, anyway you will require to download those files even minified to run application on client browser